# How to allow only admin or site owners to edit web parts?

Tags: web-part, permissions

I am creating a sharepoint site in which I have a separate group that only contributes by adding documents to the library. But creating a contribute permission group is allowing the user to edit the web part. Also, I created a separate permission level so that the users cannot edit web part but then it is not allowing users to add documents. It is displaying access denied message.

How can prevent particular group of users from editing the web part but also allow users to add documents to the library or lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the users to be able to work with documents, you can break the role inheritance on the document library.

Then you give the editing users higher permissions only on that library and not on the whole site.

Details on how to break permission inheritance is found [here](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Manage-permissions-for-a-list-library-folder-document-or-list-item-9d13e7df-a770-4646-91ab-e3c117fcef45)